# MySQL reorder string using regexp?

Tags: mysql, regex, timestamp

I have a mysql table with a varchar fields containing date values in the format;

"dd/mm/yyyy"

I would like to reorder these string values, and create a datetime value or a timestamp, so I can order properly by this column. I am not an expert with regex, but I think this could be the way forward.

I would like to end up with the table of dates in the following format;

yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00

I, hoping that I should (?) then be able to alter the column data type to timestamp or date time.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: In your use case, regexp are not required !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for this, and should probably avoid it given out-of-the-box functions that handle this specific scenario.

Check out the MySql [`STR_TO_DATE()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

> It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE()
>   returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and
>   time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date
>   or time parts.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('31/4/2004', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Returns:

```
 '2004-04-31'
```

To force a DATETIME you could concatenate a time string to the end of your field's date string, eg:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(myDateColumn, ' ', '00:00:00'), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s');
```

Comment: Thanks @Sepster, that worked great. I didn't have to concat the 00 part, as it threw an error - the working call I used was; UPDATE table_name SET start_date = STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') WHERE id > 0;

Comment: @ChristyHerron absolutely my pleasure, thanks for taking the time to respond/accept.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use MySQL regex, because in MySQL regex is allowed only for search.

Comment: You _could_ use it, in theory, as part of a _where_ clause in a series of _update_ statements, but it would be complex and unwieldy, highly impractical.  Otherwise regexes _can_ be employed in a user defined function to perform such tasks. As per my answer I wouldn't recommend this for @ChristyHerron as there's purpose built functionality already available for this, but there may be other (eg non date, problem/business domain specific) uses for a regex based search/replace such as https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp